# Where can I get the Petri's Philter recipe?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have found the enhanced petri's philter, but I can't find the basic recipe. I would assume it's from a merchant, but I've checked most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a recipe for Petri's Philtre on the first floor (up the ladder), at Drahim Castle, in Velen.

[image]

> From the pictured Quick Travel point, walk towards the left of the castle. You will see a doorway that can be broken with Aard or sword. Walk through the doorway, and climb up the ladder found within. The formula is in a lootable box near the next ladder up.

This is likely one of **many** locations to find this formula, and it's possible that it was a randomly generated loot item.